# Echo to ttyS0 don't work from bash script

Tags: linux, echo, tty

My linux - RHEL 6.0.

I've encountred with strange problem. I need that ntpd start on the boot time, therefore I create symbolic link (S99ntpd) in the /etc/rc.d/rc3.d directory...................but necessary to **do some actions before** ntpd started.

Default boot level is 3.

This is start func in the ntpd script (that store in the /etc/init.d directory)

```
start()
{
stty 9600 -F /dev/ttyS0  
sleep 1
echo -ne "\x10\x43\x01\x00\x01\x00\x10\x03" > /dev/ttyS0 
sleep 1
echo -ne "\$PSDES,RS,1,4800,OFF*22\r\n" > /dev/ttyS0 
sleep 1
stty 4800 -F /dev/ttyS0
sleep 1
echo -ne "\$PSDES,NAV,GPS*4c\r\n" > /dev/ttyS0 
sleep 1
echo -ne "\$PSDES,PNO,GGA,ON*6c\r\n" > /dev/ttyS0 
sleep 1..................
```

As result echo command **don't invoke** in the ntpd script at boot time..................But when I execute after login (i.e. service ntpd start) , that all work properly.

Comment: Are you actually calling the `ntpd` daemon after all these sleep/echo? Because in your code there is no such call...

Comment: Thanks rodrigo. Ntpd daemon starts successfully, but echo to com port don't work at boot time.

Comment: I don't understand why echo to com port work properly after login , but at boot time (from /etc/init.d/ntpd script ) don't work.

Comment: May it be related to the `$PSDES` environment variable? That may be defined in your shell (`~/profile`?) but not in the system shell.

Comment: I think NO , look at '\' symbol at the begin of the string and '-e' option of the 'echo' command.

Comment: Ok... another guess: `echo` is an intrinsic command in some shells, but an external command in others. And maybe you are using different shells in the boot and manual runs. Try replacing `echo` with `/bin/echo`.

Comment: Rodrigo, I discover another fact. If move this commands (echo xxxxxx > /dev/ttyS0) to rc.local (that /etc/rc.d) that works right too.

Comment: No, Rodrigo. Your advice about (/bin/echo) don't help.

Comment: Friends, any suggestions???

Comment: Sorry, I'm out of ideas. The only thing I can think of is that `/dev/ttyS0` does not exist yet when the services are run, but it does exist when `/etc/rc.d` is run. Maybe `udev` is delaying things or something...

Comment: maybe permissions????